# frank () form multiple columns in R

Tags: r, data.table, ranking

I happen to stumble upon a problem with frank(). I have a `data.table` with multiple columns, containing and itemID and its characteristics. Now i would like to order the items according to its characteristics: `total` and `RD`, which are both values. The higher the values of both columns, the higher the ranks. Additionally, I want to rank for each `type` separately.

[image]

```
testDT <- testDT[,rankRD := frank(RD), by = c("type")]
testDT <- testDT[,rankTotal := frank(total), by = c("type")]
```

I have build an get around:

```
Sumrank <- rowSums(testDT[,c("rankRD", "rankTotal")])
testDT <- cbind(testDT, Sumrank)
testDT <- testDT[,rank := frank(-Sumrank), by = c("type")]
```

However, this is not a very elegant solution. I was looking for a better solution, that is suitable for large data too - ideally `data.table`

Example data:

```
item <- c(rep(c("plan20, plan21, plan22"), 2), "plan23", "plan24", "plan25")
item <- c("plan20", "plan21", "plan22", "plan20", "plan21", "plan22", "plan23","plan24", "plan25")
total <- c(rep(c(3000, 5000, 7000), 2), c(5000, 5000, 2000))
RD <- c(rep(c(500, 300, 700), 2), c(500, 200, 100))
type <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3))
```

Comment: is it necessary to replicate your values of `rank` or you just need the ordering to be in place?

Comment: no, that was just for me ... i am interested to get a single final rank value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option for this equal weighted rank calculations:

```
#convert type into integer type for easier joining later and
#create an running index for RD
testDT[order(type, RD), c("tid", "rd") := .(rleid(type), rleid(type, RD))]

#create an running index for total
testDT[order(tid, total), rt := rleid(tid, total)]

#create an running index for sum of indices in descending order
testDT[order(tid, -(rd+rt)), rr := rleid(tid, -(rd+rt))]

#reset the index to start with 1 for each type
testDT[testDT[, .(m=max(rr)), tid][, tid := tid + 1L], on=.(tid), rr := rr - m]
```

output:

```
     item type total  RD rankRD rankTotal Sumrank rank tid rd rt rr
1: plan20    A  3000 500      2       1.0     3.0  2.5   1  2  1  2
2: plan21    A  5000 300      1       2.0     3.0  2.5   1  1  2  2
3: plan22    A  7000 700      3       3.0     6.0  1.0   1  3  3  1
4: plan20    B  3000 500      2       1.0     3.0  2.5   2  5  4  2
5: plan21    B  5000 300      1       2.0     3.0  2.5   2  4  5  2
6: plan22    B  7000 700      3       3.0     6.0  1.0   2  6  6  1
7: plan23    C  5000 500      3       2.5     5.5  1.0   3  9  8  1
8: plan24    C  5000 200      2       2.5     4.5  2.0   3  8  8  2
9: plan25    C  2000 100      1       1.0     2.0  3.0   3  7  7  3
```

Explanation:

It sorts by `type` and either of the numeric column first and then create an index using `rleid`.  Then it sums these 2 indices and repeats for the sum of those indices while giving the top rank to those with largest sum of the previous indices.

Comment: could you maybe shortly explain the weighted rank calculations?

Comment: how would the resetting look like?